# NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID after making fake SSL cert on localhost

Tags: xampp, ssl-certificate, localhost

I've been using XAMP 3.3.0 and created a certificate for my virtual-host domain using makecert.bat

But when I goto https://local.mydomain.com/ I get

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from local.mydomain.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

with no option to bypass this check in the Advanced section.

Comment: I guess .com is a well known registered domain and should not be used in development environments. I use localdomain in my Xampp install (www.localdomain, static.localdomain, etc.) and mydomain in VirtualBox (www.mydomain, etc.) and I just receive a warning that my certificate is self-signed (which is absolutely normal). Never a message about "Attackers". There is a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700269/google-chrome-localhost-neterr-cert-authority-invalid?rq=2 involving another registered domain: .dev.